# What's the use of +$ in the give command?

Tags: regex, linux, validation, debian

what is +$ in this command:
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]

Comment: Sure that's not `[[ ... ]]`?

Comment: sorry I forget to put that.. Could you please tell me why +$ should be added?

Answer (score 2):

The `+` applies to the `[0-9]` and not the `$`.

The intended command was:

```
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

It checks if `$1` only contains digits, e.g. `123` or `9` (but not `123f` or `foo` or empty string).

It breaks down as:

- `[[`, start of a Bash extended test command
- `$1`, the first parameter
- `=~`, the Bash extended test command regex match operator
- `^[0-9]+$`, the regex to match against:

  - `^`, anchor matching the start of the line
  - `[0-9]+`, one or more digits

    - `[0-9]`, a digit
    - `+`, one or more of the preceding atom
  - `$`, anchor matching the end of the line
- `]]` to terminate the test command

Answer (score 1):

`+` in regexp matches for "1 or more times the preceding pattern" and `$` signifies the end of string anchor.

`^` is beginning of string anchor (the natural complement to `$`), and `[0-9]` matches any single digit (in the range of 0 to 9).